# vb compare reply from serial port

Tags: vb.net

How to make `RESULT` Textbox show "PASS" by comparing `REPLY` Textbox "OK" with `REF` Textbox "OK".

My problem is `RESULT` textbox  showed "NG" even `REPLY` textbox is same with `REF` textbox. It should show "PASS" in `RESULT` textbox

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1
    Delegate Sub SetTextCallBack(ByVal [text] As String)

    Private Sub writeButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles writeButton.Click

        SerialPort1.Close()
        SerialPort1.PortName = "COM5"
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = "9600"
        SerialPort1.Open()
        SerialPort1.Write(inputTextBox.Text & vbCr)

        If REPLYtxtBox.Text = REFtxtBox.Text Then
            RESULTtxtBox.Text = "PASS"
        Else
            RESULTtxtBox.Text = "NG"
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())

    End Sub

    Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)
        If Me.REPLYtxtBox.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallBack(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.REPLYtxtBox.Text &= [text]
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It takes time to get the command transmitted, processed by the device and the reply to get sent back.  Milliseconds, you expect it to happen in a fraction of a nanosecond.  ReadExisting() is a dangerous method, even though it describes exactly what it does.  It only returns the data that is existing, at 9600 baud that is usually only 1 character.  A device that sends an "OK" response usually allows using ReadLine() instead.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   SerialPort1.Write(inputTextBox.Text & vbCr)
>
>   If REPLYtxtBox.Text = REFtxtBox.Text Then
> ```

Your comparing received text before giving it a chance to be received, at 9600bps and serial port overhead a single character will take >1ms to arrive, but your checking in the very next statement which will be reached in microseconds.

You need to move the check until after data has been received (part of the handling of `DataReceived` event).

Comment: I 've changed my code by adding another push button which will compare the REPLYtxtbox with REFtxtbox and will show the result in RESULTtxtbox.The result is still the same, it will show "NG" in the RESULTtxtbox

Comment: @Art76 In that case, please edit the question to include the values of the `Text` properties of the various controls (use the debugger to get the actual values, don't rely on cut and paste from the UI).